# Sequelize: s.replace not a function when using literal update

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this snippet:

```
return await SongQueue.update({
    queue: literal('queue - 1') }, {
    where: {
        guildId: guild.id,
        [Op.gte]: from,
        [Op.lte]: to,
    },
});
```

And I got this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: s.replace is not a function

What's wrong with this snippet?

Types:
`queue`, `from`, `to`: int
`guild.id`: string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set the columns for the `Op` filters:

```
guildId: guild.id,
queue: {
    [Op.gte]: from,
    [Op.lte]: to,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access sequelize literal by that. Instead try this.

```
return await SongQueue.update(
    { 
        queue: sequelize.literal('queue - 1')
    }, 
    {
    where: {
        guildId: guild.id,
        [Op.gte]: from,
        [Op.lte]: to,
    },
});
```

Comment: The literal is required on the start of the file like this: `const { Op, literal } = require('sequelize');`